# Конвертирование string в int c#

Tags: c#

Есть стринговое значение:

```
web_selenium.FindElement(By.XPath("//p[@class='amount']")).Text
//Значение может быть 10.11 или просто 10
```

Я пытаюсь его преобразовать в int:

```
int account_balance = Convert.ToInt32(web.FindElement(By.XPath("//p[@class='amount']")).Text);
```

Выдаёт FormatException.
В чём может быть беда?
Читал уже про культуру, попробовал создать переменную double. Создаётся у меня так:

```
double d = 1.1;
```

Comment: Ошибку выдаёт только когда 10.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int account_balance = (int)Convert.ToDecimal(web.FindElement(By.XPath("//p[@class='top-b-acc__amount']")).Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Конвертируйте в decimal, потом округляйте:

```
int account_balance = (int)Convert.ToDecimal("10.11");
```

Comment: А где у вас округление?

Comment: @PashaPash♦ Добавил строку: http://prntscr.com/oivc9q, чтобы проверить возвращаемые данные: http://prntscr.com/oivbe3 . Однако, когда начал выполнение кода всё равно вернуло ошибку: http://prntscr.com/oivdi9 . Так выглядит изменённый код: int account_balance = (int)Convert.ToDecimal(web.FindElement(By.XPath("//p[@class='top-b-acc__amount']")).Text);

Comment: @Raider как я понял, это (int) перед конвертированием в Decimal

Comment: Приведение типа просто вернет целую часть числа, а не округлит в традиционном понимании.

Comment: @Raider для меня не важно что будет после точки. Главное, чтобы вернулось то, что было до запятой. Но почему-то не выходит..

Comment: Потому что забыли передать `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` вторым параметром.

Comment: @Raider все верно. Это типичная проблема при преобразовании строки в число с плавающей точкой. Для каждой `Culture` определен свой разделитель. Для *ru-RU* - это запятая, поэтому он и бросает исключение формата, если на вход подавать `10.11`.